# R function to solve a quadratic equation

Tags: r

I am trying to solve for x of the following quadratic equation:

[image]

where

```
a_i<-c(9,27,37,47)
b_i<-c(70,35,24,6)
a=sum(a_i)
b=sum(b_i)
d_i<-c(1,-1,-1,1)
```

I am not sure what kind of **R** function I should use. I tried `uniroot` but could not solve it. Would anyone guide me on this?

Comment: `optim` or `optimize`?

Comment: I tried ```optim``` but I don't think I understand the restriction that requires by ```optim```.